# some questions about jQuery $.get() method

Tags: jquery

when i learn jquery,i met the question as below:

```
<form id="form1" action="get1.php">
<p>评论：</p>
<p>姓名：<input type="text" name="username" id="username"/></p>
<p>内容：<textarea name="content" id="content" rows="2" cols="20"></textarea> 
</p>
<p><input type="button" id="send" value="提交"/></p>
</form>
<div class="comment">已有评论</div>
<div id="resText"></div>
<script>
$(function () {
    $("#send").click(function () {
        $.get("get1.php",{
            username:$("#username").val(),
            content:$("#content").val()
        },function(data,textStatus){
            $("#resText").html(data);
        })
    })
})
</script>
```

i want to known why when i click the button ,it didn't show anything.thanks a lot.

Comment: did you get any errors in your console.

Comment: you also need to cancel the form submittion

Comment: sorry,i don't what do you mean.could you explain it.

Comment: the form post likely is causing a full page refresh. i'd remove the form.

Comment: After i remove the form ,when i click the button it also didn't show anything.i want to known if i remove the form ,i should use which url

Comment: You need to bind the `submit` event, not click. You also need to pass the event object to the callback function and do `e.preventDefault()`

Answer (score 0):

You should use post function to send data to server, get request should be used only for getting some data. Also make sure you have included jQuery library in your page.

```
$("#send").click(function () {
        $.post("get1.php",{
            username:$("#username").val(),
            content:$("#content").val()
        },function(data,textStatus){
            $("#resText").html(data);
        })
    })
```